# сохранение данных об авторизации в приложение

Tags: java, android-studio, авторизация

Я начинающий java программист, и недавно меня попросили сделать на заказ простенькое приложение, но есть одна загвоздка: при каждом входе приходится заново проходить авторизацию. После экрана загрузки пользователя перекидывает в окно аутентификации, но, по идее, если пользователь авторизирован, то после экрана загрузки его должно перекинуть на другое activity. Подскажите как это реализовать.
Вот код экрана загрузки:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Authoriz.class));
        finish();
    }
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы для таких целей советовал использовать [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences). Суть вот в чем - при успешной авторизации вы в память телефона записываете переменную, которая отображает состояние авторизации. При логауте вы меняете состояние этой переменной на "не_авторизован". Вот код для записи переменной:

```
SharedPreferences mSettings = getSharedPreferences("my_storage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("is_logged", true).apply();
```

таким образом, переменная `is_logged` со значением true будет соответствовать тому что юзер уже логинился. Дальше при запуске активности, вам нужно будет проверять эту переменную и если она true то переходить дальше:

```
if(mSettings.getBoolean("is_visited", false)){
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Authoriz.class));
finish();
}else{
// пользователь не авторизован
}
```

Эту переменную `SharedPreferences mSettings;` можно сделать глобальной, а инициализировать в методе `onCreate()`:

```
mSettings = getSharedPreferences("my_storage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Вот есть туториалы по работе с sharedPreferences: [1](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/sharedpreferences.php) и [2](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/73-urok-33-hranenie-dannyh-preferences.html).